Solana validator doesnt start on port 8899 using it as rpc
I am trying to start an full rpc on mainnet.
I keep getting these logs.
what is rebuilt storages for 134832/414439 slots with 0 collisions
Apr 19 07:23:14 vultr validator.sh[28731]: [2024-04-19T07:23:14.669770342Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: disk-stats reads_completed=722i reads_merged=0i sectors_read=184832i time_reading_ms=9737i writes_completed=139i writes_merged=740i sectors_written=161872i time_writing_ms=26352i io_in_progress=0i time_io_ms=4988i time_io_weighted_ms=34520i discards_completed=0i discards_merged=0i sectors_discarded=0i time_discarding=0i flushes_completed=0i time_flushing=0i num_disks=4i
Apr 19 07:23:15 vultr validator.sh[28731]: [2024-04-19T07:23:15.287445396Z INFO  solana_runtime::snapshot_utils::snapshot_storage_rebuilder] rebuilt storages for 134832/414439 slots with 0 collisions
Apr 19 07:23:15 vultr validator.sh[28731]: [2024-04-19T07:23:15.961805698Z INFO  solana_metrics::metrics] datapoint: net-stats-validator in_datagrams_delta=5i no_ports_delta=0i in_errors_delta=2i out_datagrams_delta=5i rcvbuf_errors_delta=2i sndbuf_errors_delta=0i in_csum_errors_delta=0i ignored_multi_delta=0i in_errors=3571587i rcvbuf_errors=3571587i sndbuf_errors=395i rx_bytes_delta=5614i rx_packets_delta=15i rx_errs_delta=0i rx_drops_delta=0i rx_fifo_delta=0i rx_frame_delta=0i tx_bytes_delta=9055i tx_packets_delta=16i tx_errs_delta=0i tx_drops_delta=0i tx_fifo_delta=0i tx_colls_delta=0i

when I run this
#!/bin/bash

#!/bin/bash

# Set PATH
export RUST_LOG=info
export RUST_BACKTRACE=1

exec solana-validator \
    --identity /root/validator-keypair.json \
    --trusted-validator 7Np41oeYqPefeNQEHSv1UDhYrehxin3NStELsSKCT4K2 \
    --trusted-validator GdnSyH3YtwcxFvQrVVJMm1JhTS4QVX7MFsX56uJLUfiZ \
    --trusted-validator DE1bawNcRJB9rVm3buyMVfr8mBEoyyu73NBovf2oXJsJ \
    --trusted-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S \
    --expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
    --snapshot-interval-slots 500 \
    --maximum-local-snapshot-age 500 \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
    --full-rpc-api \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8014 \
    --no-voting \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --snapshot-archive-format lz4 \
    --no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader \
    --limit-ledger-size 50000000 \
    --init-complete-file /var/root/data/init-completed \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --log - \


And when I try this I get

it is stuck here for hours.
Any help?
the service file is this
[Unit]
Description=Solana Validator Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Environment="PATH=/root/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin:$PATH"
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=inherit
ExecStart=/root/solana-rpc-setup/validator.sh
User=root
Restart=always
LimitNOFILE=1000000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

System Specifications Overview
Network Speed

Download: 1893.74 Mbps
Upload: 1440.93 Mbps

Storage Capacity

/dev/vdb2

Total: 1.2 TB
Used: 97 GB
Available: 994 GB


tmpfs

Total: 3.2 GB
Used: 0 GB
Available: 3.2 GB



CPU Specifications

Model: AMD EPYC-Rome Processor
Architecture: x86_64
CPU(s): 16
Cores per Socket: 8
Thread(s) per Core: 2
Total Threads: 32
CPU MHz: 1996.249
L1 Cache: 256 KiB (d) / 256 KiB (i)
L2 Cache: 4 MiB
L3 Cache: 16 MiB
Virtualization Type: Full
Hypervisor Vendor: Microsoft

Operating System

System: Unix-based, running on a Microsoft hypervisor


This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but do you have disks mounted at /mnt/accounts and /mnt/ledger? It's hard to tell from your configuration

yes I have mounted and made partitions

Could be that the server you're running the validator is not powerful enough to process the ledger efficiently, and it takes a lot of time to get started, during start-up port 8899 is not being used, this is normal.
Check this for hardware requirements: https://docs.solanalabs.com/operations/requirements

Hi I updated the server specs, can you please tell me why  my validator is stuck in this phase?

what is rebuild storages for 204126/405752 slots with 0 collisions
